# Create editable polygon and after editing it get the edited lat Lng in any event

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.draw

Below is my code to create polygon , i want to make this editable so, I have passed  " editable:true" option to map.
But still shape is not editable.

```
this.map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, {editable: true}).setView(DEFAULT_LAT_LONG, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    this.drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map);
    this.drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        position: 'topright',
        draw: {
            polygon: {
                shapeOptions: CONSTANTS.POLYGON_OPTION,
                allowIntersection: false,
                drawError: {
                    color: 'orange',
                    timeout: 1000
                },
                showArea: true,
                metric: false,
                repeatMode: false
            }
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: this.drawnItems
        }
    });
    this.drawHandler = new L.Draw.Polygon(this.map,this.drawControl.options.draw.polygon);
    this.drawHandler.enable();
    this.map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
        this.drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
        this.calculateArea(e.layer);
        this.mapState = MAP_STATE.NONE;
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Don't you want to make the polygon editable?  You probably need to pass the `editable:true` in the polygon constructor rather than the map constructor.

Comment: I also did that , but it is not working .

Comment: Leaflet doesn't support editable shapes, you'll need an additional library(e.g. [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) )

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/3EQ9X/6/

Comment: @HoussemFat : I have added editable:true , and now my polygon is editable. If we edit created polygon then in which map event we can get edited layer ?

Comment: @user3032373, hi, there are a list of event, same as draw:created  , there is 'draw:edited'.

Comment: @HoussemFat: Actually i have tried all those events. but i got to know that my leaflet.Draw version was 0.2.2 and i upgraded it to 0.3.0-dev and now using 'Draw:editvertices' . it is working with this version now.
Now learning about geoJson(). I have written code. but I am not at all satisfied with the code.  I just want to know the standard practice to code in mapbox.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `editable: true` in options.

refer this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes